# Insert rows from dataframeB to DataframeA with keys and without Merge

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` with thousand records  as:

```
ID to    from    Date     price    Type 

1  69    18     2/2020     10       A
2  11    12     2/2020      5       A
3  18    10     3/2020      4       B
4  10    11     3/2020     10       A
5  12    69     3/2020      4       B 
6  12    20     3/2020      3       B
7  69    21     3/2020      3       A
```

The output that i want is :

```
     ID to   from     Date    price    Type  ID  to   from     Date    price    Type 
     1  69    18     2/2020     4        A    5  12    69      3/2020     4      B 
     1' 69    18     2/2020     6        A    Nan  Nan  Nan     Nan      Nan   Nan
     2  11    12     2/2020     5        A    Nan  Nan  Nan     Nan      Nan    Nan 
     4  10    11     3/2020     4        A     3  18    10    3/2020     4       B
     4' 10    11     3/2020     6        A    Nan   Nan   Nan    Nan     Nan   Nan
    Nan Nan   Nan     Nan      Nan      Nan    6     12    20   3/2020     3     B              
    7  69    21     3/2020      3       A     Nan   Nan   Nan    Nan    Nan    Nan
```

The idea is to iterate over row , if the type is B ,  put the row next to the first record with type A and from = TO ,
if the price are equals its ok , if  its not split the row with higher price , and the new price will be soustracted.

i divise the dataframe in type A and B , and im trying to iterate both of them

```
grp = df.groupby('type')

transformed_df_list = []

for idx, frame in grp:
frame.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
transformed_df_list.append(frame.copy())
A = pd.DataFrame([transformed_df_list[0])
B=  pd.DataFrame([transformed_df_list[1])
for i , row in A.iterrows(): 
    for i, row1 in B.iterrows(): 
        if row['to'] == row1['from']:
           if row['price'] == row1['price']:
            row_df = pd.DataFrame([row1])
            output = pd.merge(A ,B,  how='left' , left_on =['to'] ,  right_on =['from'] )
```

The problem is that with merge function a get several duplicate rows and i cant check the price to split the row ?
There is way to insert B row in A dataframe witout merge function ?

Comment: is duplicate rows your only concern with merge?

Comment: Not only , i dont know how to check the price and split ?

Comment: What do you mean by split the row? and does from=to mean from of df A = to of df B?

Comment: yep , if dfa['to'] == dfb['from']  and dfa['price'] == dfb['price']  just insert row dfb next , if dfa['price'] > dfb['price'] , split row dfa and  the new price row is dfa['price']= dfa['price'] -  dfb['price']

Comment: Again, what do you mean by split?

Comment: duplicate row and change the price in the second row duplicated

Comment: are the outputs that you mentioned exactly what the mentioned dataframe should produce or just a part of it? Also, in the top dataframe, are the headers correct (to before from?)

Comment: @SajanGohil Can i check now

Comment: sure, but i will be able to reply later